# Assign query result to variable - GBQ Python Client

Tags: python, google-bigquery

I'm using the Google Big Query Python Client Library. One of the queries I'm running is a simple count of the number of tables in the dataset and I wanted to know if there is a neater way to assign the query result to a variable than the way I am currently doing it.

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

query = """
    SELECT count(*)
    AS table_count
    FROM project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
"""


table_count = client.query(query) # returns a query job object

for row in table_count
    count = row[0] # assign count value to single variable
```

Is there a way to do this without needing to use a loop to access the values in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn about the pandas, then you can assign your result directly to Pandas data frame. With this data frame, you can do whatever you want to process your data.
Here is the example [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/samples/bigquery-query-results-dataframe)

PS: pandas is famous data processing framework in Python. If you want to learn how to process data with Python, pandas is a must.

Comment: Thanks! That looks like what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

It's likely easiest to simply use the list constructs you're happiest with and break once you have the first row, as the results are available via an iterable.

Adapting your example:

```
from google.cloud import bigquery

client = bigquery.Client()

query = """
    SELECT count(*)
    AS table_count
    FROM project.dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
"""

job = client.query(query)

results = job.result()

for row in results:
  print(f'there were {row[0]} tables')
  break
```

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the [`query job object`](https://googleapis.dev/python/bigquery/latest/generated/google.cloud.bigquery.job.QueryJob.html) into a `dataframe` as follows-

```
df = client.query(query).to_dataframe()
```